# How to store names under a specific group [R]

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a dataframe that looks like so

```
  Continent_Name Continent_Code Country_Name         Two_Letter_Coun~
  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>                <chr>           
1 Asia           AS             Afghanistan, Islami~ AF              
2 Europe         EU             Albania, Republic of AL              
3 Antarctica     AN             Antarctica (the ter~ AQ              
4 Africa         AF             Algeria, People's D~ DZ              
5 Oceania        OC             American Samoa       AS              
6 Europe         EU             Andorra, Principali~ AD
```

I am trying to make a list with all 7 continents, and store each country that belongs to that continent in the same group. In other words, I want to create a list of the 7 different continents and each of the 7 continent's countries are in their related groups.

What is a good way to go about this?

Comment: What format do you want the country names to be in in each element of the list? Also, depending on what you are trying to do afterwards, it might just be easiest to transform to a single long `data.frame` where each row is a country but and you have a column to indicate the continent. Then you could use `dplyr::group_by()` and perform operations within each group.

Comment: I am just trying to get a list of 7 with each of the countries in their respective groups. Also, the format could be the actual country names or the abbreviations; it does not make a difference to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`. With data.frame `d`, that would be something like

```
x <- split(d, d$Continent_Name)
```

Or perhaps

```
x <- split(d$Country_Name, d$Continent_Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your downstream application different output formats may be most useful. Here are a few examples with the sample `gapminder` dataset to simulate your situation.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

# simulate something like the original data you show
g <- gapminder %>% 
  distinct(continent, country) %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  summarise(country = paste0(country, collapse = ", "))

g
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   continent country                                                             
#>   <fct>     <chr>                                                               
#> 1 Africa    Algeria, Angola, Benin, Botswana, Burkina Faso, Burundi, Cameroon, ~
#> 2 Americas  Argentina, Bolivia, Brazil, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Costa Rica, Cu~
#> 3 Asia      Afghanistan, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Cambodia, China, Hong Kong, China~
#> 4 Europe    Albania, Austria, Belgium, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Bulgaria, Croati~
#> 5 Oceania   Australia, New Zealand

# option if you just split into a list without separating country names
g %>% 
  group_split(continent)
#> <list_of<
#>   tbl_df<
#>     continent: factor<be586>
#>     country  : character
#>   >
#> >[5]>
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   continent country                                                             
#>   <fct>     <chr>                                                               
#> 1 Africa    Algeria, Angola, Benin, Botswana, Burkina Faso, Burundi, Cameroon, ~
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   continent country                                                             
#>   <fct>     <chr>                                                               
#> 1 Americas  Argentina, Bolivia, Brazil, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Costa Rica, Cu~
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   continent country                                                             
#>   <fct>     <chr>                                                               
#> 1 Asia      Afghanistan, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Cambodia, China, Hong Kong, China~
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   continent country                                                             
#>   <fct>     <chr>                                                               
#> 1 Europe    Albania, Austria, Belgium, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Bulgaria, Croati~
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   continent country               
#>   <fct>     <chr>                 
#> 1 Oceania   Australia, New Zealand

# split and parse back into a list of data.frames
g %>% 
  group_split(continent) %>% 
  map(~separate_rows(.x, country, sep = ", "))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 54 x 2
#>    continent country                 
#>    <fct>     <chr>                   
#>  1 Africa    Algeria                 
#>  2 Africa    Angola                  
#>  3 Africa    Benin                   
#>  4 Africa    Botswana                
#>  5 Africa    Burkina Faso            
#>  6 Africa    Burundi                 
#>  7 Africa    Cameroon                
#>  8 Africa    Central African Republic
#>  9 Africa    Chad                    
#> 10 Africa    Comoros                 
#> # ... with 44 more rows
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 25 x 2
#>    continent country           
#>    <fct>     <chr>             
#>  1 Americas  Argentina         
#>  2 Americas  Bolivia           
#>  3 Americas  Brazil            
#>  4 Americas  Canada            
#>  5 Americas  Chile             
#>  6 Americas  Colombia          
#>  7 Americas  Costa Rica        
#>  8 Americas  Cuba              
#>  9 Americas  Dominican Republic
#> 10 Americas  Ecuador           
#> # ... with 15 more rows
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 37 x 2
#>    continent country    
#>    <fct>     <chr>      
#>  1 Asia      Afghanistan
#>  2 Asia      Bahrain    
#>  3 Asia      Bangladesh 
#>  4 Asia      Cambodia   
#>  5 Asia      China      
#>  6 Asia      Hong Kong  
#>  7 Asia      China      
#>  8 Asia      India      
#>  9 Asia      Indonesia  
#> 10 Asia      Iran       
#> # ... with 27 more rows
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 30 x 2
#>    continent country               
#>    <fct>     <chr>                 
#>  1 Europe    Albania               
#>  2 Europe    Austria               
#>  3 Europe    Belgium               
#>  4 Europe    Bosnia and Herzegovina
#>  5 Europe    Bulgaria              
#>  6 Europe    Croatia               
#>  7 Europe    Czech Republic        
#>  8 Europe    Denmark               
#>  9 Europe    Finland               
#> 10 Europe    France                
#> # ... with 20 more rows
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   continent country    
#>   <fct>     <chr>      
#> 1 Oceania   Australia  
#> 2 Oceania   New Zealand

# parse out country names and merge back into single long data.frame
g %>% 
  group_split(continent) %>% 
  map(~separate_rows(.x, country, sep = ", ")) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 148 x 2
#>    continent country                 
#>    <fct>     <chr>                   
#>  1 Africa    Algeria                 
#>  2 Africa    Angola                  
#>  3 Africa    Benin                   
#>  4 Africa    Botswana                
#>  5 Africa    Burkina Faso            
#>  6 Africa    Burundi                 
#>  7 Africa    Cameroon                
#>  8 Africa    Central African Republic
#>  9 Africa    Chad                    
#> 10 Africa    Comoros                 
#> # ... with 138 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>